# Calculating wavelengths from angles in a diffraction grating?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light, waves, diffraction

I am having some problems calculating wavelengths from some given information about a grating spectrum.

**A diffraction grating with a spacing of 3μm is used in a spectrometer to investigate the emission spectrum of a mercury vapour discharge lamp.**

**The spectrum is examined over the range of angles from 30° to 50°, and maxima of intensity are observed at the angles and with the colours shown in the table. No other maxima are observed in this range of angles.**

```
Violet: 32.7°, 42.4°  
Blue:   35.5°, 46.6°  
Green:  33.1°, 46.7°  
Yellow: 35.2°, 35.4°
```

To calculate wavelengths, I know that: $n\lambda = dsin \theta$.
So for the first angle: $n\lambda = 3 \times 10^{-6} \times sin 32.7$
However, I'm not sure where to go from there as I don't know what order of maxima they are as 0° to 30° is not examined. I have tried guessing numbers to make sure the wavelengths are in the range 400nm to 700nm. For example, with values of n=4 (35.5°) and n=5 (46.6°) for the blue light I get wavelength values that both round to 436nm, but this is apparently incorrect.

Also I don't understand how the two yellow maxima are so close together because this would normally mean there is a tiny wavelength, much smaller than that of visible light.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: If there are no maxima in violet **between** 32.7 and 42.4, what does that tell you about the relationship between the value of $n$ for each?

Comment: While Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each wavelength you have been given (exactly) two values $\theta$, so

$$\begin{align}n\lambda &= d\sin\theta_1\\
(n+1)\lambda &= d\sin\theta_2\end{align}$$

subtracting these two equations, we get

$$\lambda = d\left(\sin\theta_2-\sin\theta_1\right)$$

You should be able to figure it out from there...

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that the value for n does not have to be an integer, and so I didn't think about forming this equation.